# Effective Exception handling with spark and scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I know the question is not something new but my context is different.I have been trying best possible way to handle exceptions effectively.Below is my experimental code

```
val in = List("1", "2", "3", "abc")
val sc = prepareConfig();
val rdd = sc.parallelize(in)
val mapRDD = rdd.map { x => Try { x.toInt } }
val successRDD = mapRDD.filter { x => x.isSuccess }
val successRDD2 = 
successRDD.map { x => Try { x.get * x.get } }.filter{ _.isSuccess }
.
. // some more Transformation operations based on the use case
.

successRDD10.collect()
```

Assume that I may need to have 10 transformations which leads to end result. Should I need to have Try{} for all my transformations ? Expectation  is I may get error in any of the 10 transformations.So i'm trying to filter successful results and passing it to next stage. so is the above one is effective way of exception handling  or any other alternative approach recommended ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way:

```
val res: RDD[Int] = rdd.flatMap(x => Try(x.toInt).map(i => i * i).toOption)
```

It really does what you are trying to achieve. How?

1. Each `String` is converted into an `Int`: `Try(x.toInt)`
2. **If the conversion is successful**, the integer is multiplied by itself: `map(i => i * i)`
3. The resulting `Try[Int]` is converted to an `Option[Int]` that is `None` if the `Try[Int]` is a `Failure` and `Some(value)` otherwise: `toOption`
4. Thanks to the `flatMap` operation, only `Option[Int]` that are defined (i.e not `None`, thus the conversion was successful) remain in the resulting `RDD[Int]`

No need for the extra filters and `isSuccess` calls.

Comment: What about if wanted to make use of DataFrames and its sql expression and there are such runtime exception due to data. Is there a way to handle the same?